# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError JPA example

Tags: java, jpa, derby

So I'm trying to work through some JPA things and I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.collections.set.MapBackedSet
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.set.MapBackedSet
```

I've largely taken this code from online to get a project working first, so then I can play around with it and understand the workings. From doing some research, I think part of the problem is I'm missing the com.ibm.ws.jpa.thinclient.jar file. However I don't know where I can find that.

My persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="user" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>jpa.Main</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
        value=****Derby URL**** />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My User.Java

```
package jpa;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity
    public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userID;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }
    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
            return "Todo [summary=" + login + ", description=" + password + "]";

    }
    }
```

My main.java

```
package jpa;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class Main {

          private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "user";
          private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
          public static void main(String[] args) {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
            // Read the existing entries and write to console
            Query q = em.createQuery("select u from User u");
            List<User> userList = q.getResultList();
            for (User user : userList) {
              System.out.println(user);
            }
            System.out.println("Size: " + userList.size());
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserID(12);
            user.setPassword("This is a test");
            em.persist(user);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
          }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the commons-collections jar is available to the container at runtime?

Comment: What JPA implementation are you using? WebSphere JPA solution, based on Apache OpenJPA?

Comment: @chrylis I added that jat and got Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1084264 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException Along with two ClassNotFoundExceptions and a RuntimeException

Comment: @PaulVargas I don't really know. I'm totally new to JPA, and something of a novice with Java as it is. I have Websphere Server installed, not sure about OpenJPA

Answer (score 1):

Try add commons-collections jar file to your library 
[Refer This Commons-collections](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonscollectionsjar.htm)

Comment: Tried that and got:

Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1084264 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException Along with two ClassNotFoundExceptions and a RuntimeException

Comment: If you happen to use maven, add this as dependency: <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the file `com.ibm.ws.jpa.thinclient.jar` to the classpath. If you have already Websphere installed, you can find this file. e.g.:

```
C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\runtimes\com.ibm.ws.jpa.thinclient_7.0.0.jar
```

In another way, if you choose the Reference Implementation of JPA ([EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink)), you don't need add this jar.

Comment: I tried this and I got this error:

Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1084264 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException

Along with two ClassNotFoundExceptions and a RuntimeException

Answer (score 0):

You have to add jar file where org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver resides and com.ibm.ws.jpa.thinclient_8.5.0.jar as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

is this too little too late?  It looks like your "User" class is not named in persistence.xml.  You just have:

```
<class>jpa.Main</class>
```

Did you try changing 'jpa.Main' to 'jpa.User'?  I don't think you need to name jpa.Main in persistence.xml, just jpa.User.  User is your entity class.